# Tapping on detected data on a UITextView inside a custom UITableViewCell calls didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: uitableview, uitextview, detection, didselectrowatindexpath

Alright, I have been searching every keyword combination i could think of but haven't found a solution to this yet. Everyone seems to have the opposite problem of what I am having.

I built a custom UITableViewCell with a nib file. It has a UITextView in it that displays detectable text.

After loading I can see the text has been detected and highlighted in the UITextView, however, when I go to click on it, it selects the cell, not the detected data.

The UITextView is not editable and user interaction is turned on so I should be able to get it working no?

Does anyone know what I might have to do to get it to work as intended?

If I didn't provide a piece of information that might help you help me, please let me know and I will post it.

Thanks in advance,
~Arash

Comment: I also need to add a button inside this cell so I need to figure out how to get touches down to it. I set the custom cell's background view to a UIView serving as the background for all my other objects if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but I have been trying to figure out this exact problem for more hours than I would like to admit.  Hopefully, this answer helps someone in the future.  FYI... I am using Xcode 4.3.2 at this time.

My problem was 'User Interaction Enabled'.  I had it enabled for the UITextView, but not for the custom table view cell.  If it is turned off for the table view cell, no touches will be sent to the cell or any of its subviews (ie.  the UITextView or probably a UIButton).  The only problem after I fixed that was that if you touched anywhere else in the cell, the cell would become selected.  I had to go to the Attributes Inspector, select the UITableViewCell, and change 'Selection' from 'Blue' to 'None'.

Now everything is working great.